# File.choose() when outputting data?

Tags: r

I want to use the same script to process data in many text files that are stored in different places, and then to save the output to another unique location, without having to amend my script each time.  I have input data using:

`data <- read.table(file.choose(),header=T)`

and would like to save the final table with a similar interface to select the location and enter a name for the file.

I have tried:

`write.csv(data.table,file.choose())`

but this only works if I create an empty .csv file with the name that I would like, in the location I would like before running the script.

Is there another (better) way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are doing the same thing to your input files, I would use something like:

```
# input files from working directory
all.files <- list.files()

i <- 1
while (i <= length(all.files)){

data <- read.table(all.files[i],header=T)

# your script here

# output files
out.file <- paste(gsub(".csv","", all.files[i]),"_FINAL.csv",sep="")

write.csv(data,file=out.file)

i <- i+1
}
```

Answer (score 4):

There are a few possibilities:

```
library(gWidgets)
fileName <- gfile(type = "save") 

library(tcltk)
fileName <- tclvalue(tkgetSaveFile()) 

library(svDialogs)
fileName <- dlgSave()$res
```

`dlgSave` asks for confirmation when it is needed to create a new file, `tkgetSaveFile` seems to be a bit more complicated for using additional arguments ([some basic examples](http://www.sciviews.org/_rgui/tcltk/FileOpenSave.html)) and `gfile` offers a variety of options.

Answer (score 1):

In case it went unnoticed, file.choose() also has a built in parameter that allows users to provide new file names:

```
fileName <- file.choose(new=TRUE)
```

Comment: I can't find any difference in the behaviour of `file.choose(new=TRUE)` and `file.choose(new=FALSE)`. And according to the documentation, there is no difference: "at present only new = FALSE is used".

Comment: file.name <- file.choose(new=TRUE) works for the MacGui, but not RStudio on the Mac.  The documentation states that only new=FALSE is used, although for the R.app for the Mac, new=TRUE actually works.  Does anyone know whether the new=TRUE option will eventually be added?

Answer (score 0):

file.choose(new=TRUE) works for me.

Linux (Pop!_OS 20.04), RStudio 1.3.1073